# Tensorflow: InvalidArgumentError for placeholder

Tags: tensorflow

I tried to run the following code in Jupyter Notebook, however I got the `InvalidArgumentError` for the `placeholder`.

But when I wrote a Python script and ran it in command window, it worked. I want to know how can I ran my code in the Notebook successfully, thanks.

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Tensorflow version: 0.12rc (installed from source)

Programs and Output:

[image]

[image]

Command window:

[image]

Actural code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

raw_data = np.random.normal(10, 1, 100)

# Define alpha as a constant
alpha = tf.constant(0.05)

# A placeholder is just like a variable, but the value is injected from the
# session
curr_value = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
# Initialize the previous average to some

prev_avg = tf.Variable(0.)
avg_hist = tf.summary.scalar("running_average", update_avg)
value_hist = tf.summary.scalar("incoming_values", curr_value)
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./logs")
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)
  for i in range(len(raw_data)):
    summary_str, curr_avg = sess.run([merged, update_avg], feed_dict={curr_value: raw_data[i]})
    sess.run(tf.assign(prev_avg, curr_avg))
    print(raw_data[i], curr_avg)
    writer.add_summary(summary_str, i)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please place the actual code text in your question rather than screenshots.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `raw_data` is float64 (default numpy float type) whereas your placeholder is float32 (default tensorflow float type). You should explicitly cast your data to float32

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed this issue based on your answer. By the way, I want to know why I can run my previous program in the shell successfully? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe theres something in the shell that sets numpy default to float32?